# Should emoji/emoticon replace a punctuation mark in the end of the sentence?

Tags: website-design, typography, emoji

If the sentence is finishing with emoji/emoticon in the website content or in a personal message, should it be followed by a punctuation mark?

Example #1

> **I’m glad you could make it  We had a great time.**    *– This one looks fine and clean*
>   **I’m glad you could make it . We had a great time.**   *– However this one looks weird to me*
>   **I’m glad you could make it.  We had a great time.**   *– Emoji belongs to the next sentence*
>   **I’m glad you could make it :). We had a great time.**      – This one is super-weird

Example #2

> **Is that really so ? I doubt it.**   *– This is OK, as the question mark means that it is a question*
>   **Is that really so  I doubt it.**     *– This doesn't look like a question anymore*
>   **Is that really so?  I doubt it.**   *– Again, emoji belongs to the next sentence*
>   **Is that really so =/? I doubt it.**     *– And this emoticon is something else*

So emoji/emoticon understanding varies depending on it's position. Is there a common way of using them or are there the best practices?

Comment: Do you think this question might be more suited to a forum like the English Language Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Yes, it might be. Can we move it there?

Answer (score 1):

I have a few questions:

1. what is the purpose of the emoji?
2. Is having that emoji adding what you are looking for?

The best practices I have seen are usually are at the end.

For example:

I’m glad you could make it, We had a great time.
Is that really so?  I doubt it.

It's my two cents.

Comment: Emoji gives an emotional hint, expresses the mood, makes text less formal etc.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that the emoji is replaced by words.

1. Would those words form a complete sentence?

If so, you can put the emoji after the closing punctuation mark of another sentence.

For example, “I am happy” is a complete sentence. That means you can put it between two sentences.   The capital letter at the beginning of the next sentence  indicates that this is a new sentence rather than a sentence starting with an emoji.

2. Or, would those words only form part of a sentence?

If so, you should put the emoji within the sentence, not after the closing punctuation mark.

“It is  for ” is a complete sentence — “It is time for birthday cake.” Each emoji is only part of the sentence.

And when a sentence ends with an emoji, you can sometimes omit the closing period. However, if there’s a closing exclamation mark or question mark, it should be included: “It is  for !”